# How to make style of an element dependent on another element's style

Tags: javascript, css

I need to set some special style for an element if some other element is visible (which is indicated by a special css class and can change dynamically). I need to do this because the page rendering and it's behavior is fully controlled by some framework's code and I don't want to change it. I can put any content anywhere in the body of the page. Is there a non-hacking way to do it?

My only idea was to use some plug-in like "watch" for jquery, but it's very ugly.

Comment: Hmm... As far as I can see, a property change watcher plugin is indeed the only way to go.

Comment: You can't influence what the Framework changes? You can't make it change the class of some other element in your document (a common parent to the two elements) instead of that one element's visibility? Because that's the only way I can see to make this work in CSS.

Comment: @Pekka: Thanks for confirming this. I really can't modify anything in the framework's behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the properychange/attributemodified event

```
  $("object-in-question").bind("DOMAttrModified propertychange", function(e) {
    if($(this).is(":visible")).... etc
  });
```

http://jsbin.com/abece4

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome 4, Chrome 5 (so presumably in no WebKit browser), IE 6 and IE 7.

Comment: @stereofrog your snippet didn't work for me in 6 and 7. I'll re-check later.

Comment: @stereofrog it doesn't work for me in 6 and 7, but this can be down to IETester. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, this is what the latest versions of watch plugin for jquery do (with the periodic timer driven failover in case of chrome and others).